# How to get AutoIt reference working in C#?

Tags: c#, com, autoit-c#-wrapper

I'm pulling my hair out on this one...

I have a legacy application I built a few years ago that uses AutoItX - all working fine.

The time has come to try and update the app, so I've upgraded it to VS2012/.NET4 and I simply cannot get a reference to the AutoItX library to work.

I have installed the application, have registered the dll with regsvr32, tried every combination of property settings on the reference itself (Embed Interop Types / Isolated), but no joy.

The error I keep getting whenever I try and create an AutoItX3 object is:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {1A671297-FA74-4422-80FA-6C5D8CE4DE04} failed due to the following
>   error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

Is it an issue that I'm on a 64-bit machine? I'm not trying to use the 64-bit DLL version.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay the solution was:

1. Open up regedit*32 (c:\windows\syswow64\regedit)
2. Search for AutoItX in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AppID
3. I found it in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AppID{6E8109C4-F369-415D-AF9A-2AEEFF313234}
4. Create a blank REG_SZ (String) entry called DllSurrogate

For some reason, this completely solved the issue.

Reference: [How to use a 32 bit COM object on Windows Server 2008 (works on 2008 R2 but non 2008)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043954/how-to-use-a-32-bit-com-object-on-windows-server-2008-works-on-2008-r2-but-non)

Answer (score 2):

Hainesy,

do you use a x64-Windows?
I had the same problem when I was starting to have a look at COM.
If so, you should try to register your class in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WoW6432Node\Classes...

Give it a try!

Greeting

Comment: Yes I do! Could you give me a bit more information about how I'm supposed to register the class in there? Is there a command line way of registering it?

Comment: Well, you could try a reg-script. I just started COM myself and did everything manually.
Essentially you need to register your CLSID in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WoW6432Node\Classes\{YOUR-CLSID}\ (Path to DLL (InprocServer32),
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WoW6432Node\Interface\{YOUR-IID}\

If you have ever registered an Inprocess-server, you need to put everything into HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WoW6432Node\ just like you did to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ on a 32-bit machine.