# C# application using AutoIt.dll issue

Tags: c#, autoit-c#-wrapper

I am using AutoIt dll in my C# application to get data from active windows of other program. On my computer, where I compile this application, it works OK, but when I tried to run it on other computer I got exception:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154): Pobranie fabryki klasy COM dla składnika o identyfikatorze CLSID {1A671297-FA74-4422-80FA-6C5D8CE4DE04} nie powiodło się z powodu następującego błędu: 80040154 Klasa niezarejestrowana. (Wyjątek od HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
>
> w System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
>   w System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>   w System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>          w System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
>          w System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
>          w GetFromGam.GetFromGamForm.receiveData()
>          w GetFromGam.GetFromGamForm.receiveButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
>          w System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>          w System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>          w System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
>          w System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
>          w System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>          w System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
>          w System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
>          w System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>          w System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
>          w System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

What could be wrong in this situation?

Answer (score 3):

The computer you're  trying to run your code on hasn't had the AutoIt COM interface registered. The following is from the AutoItX documentation:

> Using the COM Interface Before you can use the COM interface to
>   AutoItX it needs to be "registered" (This is done automatically when
>   you install the full version of AutoIt but you may need to do it
>   manually if you are using AutoItX separately).
>
> To register the COM interface:
>
> 1. Open a command prompt
> 2. Change directory (using CD) to the directory that contains AutoItX3.dll
> 3. Type regsvr32.exe AutoItX3.dll and press enter
>
> The name of the AutoItX control is AutoItX3.Control

Comment: I think you probably need to register the dll from an elevated command prompt, or see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14644258/get-autoit-reference-working-in-c-sharp

Comment: Okay. So could you give me a little advice, what can I do if I want to share my application? That I don't need to hange any values manually//

Comment: Easiest way is probably a batch file to automate the changes

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the correct answer - Visual Studio has an out-of-the-box project template to create an installer for your application.  That will allow you to include the dll in an installation routine.  As a result sharing the software becomes a pleasant experience to the recipient.