# i get this Error if someone test my Program: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154)

Tags: c#, .net, if-statement, while-loop

Hey i getting this Error. i puplished my C# Program and gave it to some people to test it, but they all become this error. what should i do?
i test to puplish in x64 and x86 both not works...

[image]

This error comes after he is pressing the Login Button.

Maybe some great people here know what is to do :)

Thanks
Information about invoking JIT debugging
instead of this dialog box, see the end of this message.

```
************** Exception Text **************
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154): The COM class factory for the component with CLSID {1A671297-FA74-4422-80FA-6C5D8CE4DE04} could not be retrieved due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
   at PixelAimbot.ChaosBot..ctor()
   at PixelAimbot.frmLogin.btnLogin_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

```
        using System;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using AutoItX3Lib;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Timers;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    
    
    
    namespace PixelAimbot
    {
        public partial class ChaosBot : Form
        {
            AutoItX3 au3 = new AutoItX3();
    
            public const int WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 0xA1;
            public const int HT_CAPTION = 0x2;
    
            [DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")]
            public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd,
                            int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);
            [DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")]
            public static extern bool ReleaseCapture();
    
    
            static readonly IntPtr HWND_TOPMOST = new IntPtr(-1);
    
            static readonly IntPtr HWND_NOTOPMOST = new IntPtr(-2);
    
            static readonly IntPtr HWND_TOP = new IntPtr(0);
    
            static readonly IntPtr HWND_BOTTOM = new IntPtr(1);
    
            const UInt32 SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
    
            const UInt32 SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;
    
            const UInt32 TOPMOST_FLAGS = SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE;
    
            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
            public static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);
            [DllImport("Gdi32.dll", EntryPoint = "CreateRoundRectRgn")]
            private static extern IntPtr CreateRoundRectRgn
            (
                int nLeftRect,     // x-coordinate of upper-left corner
                int nTopRect,      // y-coordinate of upper-left corner
                int nRightRect,    // x-coordinate of lower-right corner
                int nBottomRect,   // y-coordinate of lower-right corner
                int nWidthEllipse, // height of ellipse
                int nHeightEllipse // width of ellipse
            );
    
            public ChaosBot()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
    
                this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
                Region = System.Drawing.Region.FromHrgn(CreateRoundRectRgn(0, 0, Width, 

Height, 20, 20));

        }
```

Comment: Show us the code in the constructor of `ChaosBot`.

Comment: Are you using AutoIt in your code? Does AutoIt of the same version installed on the machine where the error is observed?

Comment: yes i use autoit in code. no this person dont use autoit by self... but dll is add on it.

Comment: does this helped https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41368247/c-sharp-application-using-autoit-dll-issue?

Comment: it woks : Thanks <3 but how can i add this to my puplished setup.exe to install this automatically?

Comment: The way on how to modify the setup.exe to add the automatic registration of the COM assemblies will depend on the type of installer you are using. Most common installer makers (wix/inno/install shield/etc) has their own approaches on how to add COM registration in the installer, so please refer to the installer maker's documentation. Or ask a new question with installer type specified.