# AutoIt Script using Nunit

Tags: c#, selenium, autoit

While running my script through Visual Studio (Selenium-C#), my AutoIt script for opening dialogs works perfectly, but when running the same script from the Nunit(.Net) client, the same tests are being failed getting the following error:

```js
ReportAppeal.MainTestRunner.OpenFile("Email"):
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException : Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {1A671297-FA74-4422-80FA-6C5D8CE4DE04} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
```

Anything I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay the solution was:

1. Open up regedit*32 (c:\windows\syswow64\regedit)
2. Search for AutoItX in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AppID`
   I found it in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AppID{6E8109C4-F369-415D-AF9A-2AEEFF313234}`
3. Create a blank `REG_SZ` (String) entry called `DllSurrogate`

For some reason, this completely solved the issue.
Worked in Windows 7 - 64bit

Reference:
[How to use a 32 bit COM object on Windows Server 2008 (works on 2008 R2 but non 2008)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043954/how-to-use-a-32-bit-com-object-on-windows-server-2008-works-on-2008-r2-but-non)